# How to dynamically name a range of blank cells in excel? For loop help also appreciated for the next step involving this range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a dynamic named range for a checklist. This dynamic range should reference blank cells that are sandwiched between two named cells (TestA & TestB).

The purpose of this dynamic range is to eventually be referenced when I create a macro that calls the below for loop if a certain drop down selection at the beginning of this checklist changes to "section not needed".

Right now, I am concerned with this for loop not working & my dynamic named range not working.

I keep getting this error: "Method, range of object Global Failed"

Note: If you input my formula as a named range in Excel it will in fact give you the number of blank cells for however many cells you decide to sandwich between ranges TestA & TestB, but for some reason...Excel cannot recognize that range within VBA.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

I have searched the web and youtube for instances of someone trying to reference a blank range dynamically, but have failed to find anything helpful.

**FORMULA**:
Formula used to create named range "BetweenTest"

```vb
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(TestA,1,0,1,1):OFFSET(TestB,-1,0,1,1))
```

**CODE**:

```vb
Sub FFO ()

Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In Range("BetweenTest")

If Rng.Value = "" Then

With Rng

.Value = "N/A"

End With

End If

Next Rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. It is named BetweenTest. "InBetween" was a typo on my part.

Comment: Is the name range set on workbook or worksheet level? If worksheet level you should specify the worksheet when calling the name: e.g. Sheet1.range("BetweenTest")